# Python 2.7 import requests issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, urllib3

I've tried to install requests module (Debian, Python 2.7) by `pip install requests` command. Output was:

```
Installing collected packages: urllib3, requests
Successfully installed requests-2.18.4 urllib3-1.22
```

Tried following the following [Quickstart tutorial](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) but I get the following error at `import requests`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "requests/__init__.py", line 76, in <module>
    check_compatibility(urllib3.__version__, chardet.__version__)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was with chardet package. Uninstalled it (pip uninstall chardet) and installed again and now it works. Cheers!